# Install DirectX 11.1 on Windows 10 with AMD Integrated HD 3200

Tags: windows-10, integrated-graphics, directx-11

I would like to install DirectX 11.1 on Windows 10, but I can't find a standalone installer. I have AMD HD 3200 integrated graphics.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you verified your hardware even supports DX12 because it's built into Windows 10, only version of DX that can be installed is DX 9.  Your hardware is really old, and I have doubts, it even supports DX10 or DX11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Windows 10 installed, then DirectX version 12 is installed with it.  Any new DirectX versions will be installed automatically by Windows Update.

All versions of DirectX are backwards compatible with older versions, so there is no need to install an older version of DirectX.  This allows newer machines to play games built with an older DirectX version, without the need to install previous versions of DirectX.

I have seen some really old game installers try to force the installation of an older DirectX version and fail, since a newer version is installed.  However, this should not prevent the game from running, as the newer DirectX will work.  This is due to poor programming, as the developers are wrongly looking for the latest DirectX *at the time of development*, not just a minimum required DirectX version.

Comment: i have directx 10 not 12 .

Comment: how to install 12

Comment: Click start then type 'dxdiag' and hit enter.  It should say what version of DirectX is installed on the first tab.

Comment: yes version 10 .

Comment: Have you run Windows Update?

Comment: yes . and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

DirectX 11.1 is for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and not for Windows 10

Windows 10 comes with DirectX 12

> [Install the latest version of DirectX through Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179113) 
>   Microsoft
>   DirectX is included as an integral part in Windows operating systems.
>   You can update DirectX by applying the latest service pack or other
>   updates through Windows Update.
>
> To check your DirectX version, see How to check which version of
>   DirectX is installed.  To check the latest DirectX version that you
>   can install on your operating system, see List of the latest DirectX
>   versions and their supported operating systems.

Comment: i have directx 10 not 12 .

Comment: tried to check for new versions , but nothing .

Comment: i would recommend using windows update to update it

Comment: i have tried , but shows me nothing